# How to add some space between in col-md-4?

Tags: html, css

In my school project. I am trying to create a **photo gallery** like view but I need that between two photos some space comes the code is here

```
<div class="container">
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Physics</h2>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: aliceblue;">
            <img class="img-responsive" class="thumbnail" class="img-center center-block" src="assets/GirishJain2.JPG" alt="Girish Jain">
            <p style="text-align:justify;">
                <b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Girish Jain</b> <br>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;b.Tech,IIT-Delhi<br></br>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Exp 14 years
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: lavender;">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/prateek.JPG" alt="Prateek Jain">
            <p style="text-align:justify;">
                <b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Prateek Jain</b> <br>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;b.Tech-MNIT,Jaipu<br></br>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Exp 7 years
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: aliceblue;">
            <img class="img-responsive" class="thumbnail" class="img-center center-block" src="assets/sidharthjain.JPG" alt="Siddharth Jain">
            <p style="text-align:justify;">
                <b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sidharth Jain</b> <br>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;b.Tech-MNIT,Jaipur<br></br>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Exp 14 years
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the pages like [image]
below the **physics** section I want a some space between each photo

Comment: Please provide your code as code, not as screenshot...

Comment: for the two big pictures use a div row and use col-md-6..then open another div class row for the other three pictures and use col-md-4 as you did, your problem is that you are including all of them into a single div row @Anchal Jain

Comment: yes,Just add some space between these three pictures

Comment: Use CSS [margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) or [padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding)

Comment: use something like the below 
for the big two images
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<img class="img-responsive" src=""/>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<img class="img-responsive" src=""/>

</div>
</div>

<!--for other images !-->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<img class="img-responsive" src=""/>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<img class="img-responsive" src=""/>

</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<img class="img-responsive" src=""/>

</div>
</div>

Comment: you saw in the photo the middle ones is long. how can I fixed that problem.

Comment: Please, don't use `&nbsp;` for layout.

Answer (score 1):

Allow the `col-md-4` to continue to serve it's current purpose. You want the image to be inside of a div who's job will be to give space.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
  <div class="image-padding">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Iame"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image-padding {
  padding: 5px;
}
.image-padding img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

**CodePen**

http://codepen.io/Goosecode/pen/oxaEjR

Answer (score 0):

use the below it will work fine with you wrap it inside your container div

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Iame&w=970"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Iame&w=970"/>
    
    </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <!--for other images !-->
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Iame"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Iame"/>
    
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Iame"/>
    
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: just a note, each column size works for all sizes above it. So if you put `col-xs-4` on a div, at every screen size it will take up 4 columns. There's no need to repeat yourself.

Comment: @Jhecht if you mean i shouldn't use col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4 and repeat them for the row group ?enough to use col-sm-4 ?

Comment: col-sm-4 works for small screens *or larger*.  So if you put col-xs-4 (the smallest size) it will work for extra small screens or larger.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved using Bootstrap.

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-4" id="element">
 Your Content.
</div>
```

CSS

```
#element {
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
}
```